# How can I rebase in git without resolving other commit conflicts, or squash all of my commits while leaving others' commits untouched?

Tags: git, github, merge, squash

```
 ---A---
/       \
---main--------
  \---B---+A------/
       \-----\--\C-?
```

Above is roughly the situation on my team's repo. Feature A is a giant branch that I absolutely have to leave alone. I branched off of B but have been pulling from it periodically, which means that I have all of A's changes and am up to date with main on branch C. This also means that between my first and last commit on C, there are dozens of commits plus a giant merge from A. My repo requires that each push to main be squashed, and I would like to avoid recommitting everyone else's work as my own, which is the result if I do `git reset --soft` to right before my first C commit, and `git rebase -i` forces me to resolve every single conflict, even of those that aren't my own commits.

How can I "reset" and squash all of my commits to right before I started work on C without having to resolve the conflicts of every other branch or recommit every commit as my own?

Update: I am not entirely sure how, but using `git reset --soft` to a commit in the middle of C's history actually did exactly what I wanted, pulling all of my changes into one change at the front. I'm curious about what went wrong the other time I tried that. From there, I checked out B and used `git merge --squash C`

Comment: One way to pull changes from a branch so that then you can squash all changes is by doing this: `git merge some-branch; (finish the merge if there are conflicts... when the new merge revision is done:) git reset --soft some-branch; git commit -m "single revision, no hassle"`. But you have kind of a convoluted branch history so I am not clear on what you should merge on what branch. Anyway, hope the trick allows you to move forward.

Comment: Why did you do the merges you've already done? What work in the `A` or `B` or `main` history does your work depend on? You're going to have to identify that somehow, because that's what has to be preserved in your mergeback to main.

Comment: what do you mean by resolving other conflicts? your graph looks like A and B are merged to main, so there are only your conflicts left, right? also what prevents you from doing `git merge --squash`?

Comment: Why does +A exist on B? *Especially* since it looks like A is already merged into `main`! And has B also been merged into `main`, including +A in it?

Comment: @ian If I attempted to use `git rebase -i` and squash all of my commits into one while still using the `pick` flag for everybody else's commits from C's creation until now, then I ended up having to resolve conflicts for every "picked" commit in that rebase operation

Comment: @TTT The art was a little sloppy, but I wanted to show that B was close to being pushed to main but needed C's changes first. After C branched off of B, and after A merged into main, B pulled from main since B needed to know that its changes were compatible with main in preparation to merge back into it. So really there should be a \ connecting main to B right above the `+A`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch from main. Use git cherry-pick to get B and C commits.

use git rebase -i HEAD~4 to squash last 4 commits