# Git workflow, is it ok to pull from a parallel branch

Tags: git, git-branch

The scenario I'm refering to is when I work on a feature in branch A, and a colleague on another in branch B. As I work, I realise some of the chages from B would help me a lot, but since it's work in progress, I'm not sure if I should pull from branch B in A.

My questions are:

1. Is there any disadvantage to pulling from branch B (or is it even at all recommanded to pull from other branches than develop)?
2. I realize I would now have to sync with both develop, and branch B, so next time I want the latest changes I'll need to pull from both. Is there a way to do this automatically? What if my branch depends on more than 2 branches?
3. Is there a better way to do this other than wait for branch B to be merged to develop?

I guess for most cases it would be enough to just cherry-pick some commits, but sometimes you just need the whole branch.

Comment: How would you "pull from branch B" into A? Do you mean merge? Let's try to use meaningful terminology...

Comment: And yes, there are certainly disadvantages to incorporating changes from other feature branches into your branch. It's pretty much a terrible idea, because you risk ending up committing and merging stuff that has already been committed and merged, so that (1) you present the B work as your own on A, and (2) you greatly increase the size of your branch's history and the probability of merge conflicts.

Comment: Basically the idea of working on a team is teamwork. Feature branches should be independent features. If they cannot be independent, that is, if it would be better for you if B were finished before you proceed with A, then you need to _stop and wait_ until B has been approved and merged so that you can rebase on top of develop and resume. This business where people try to incorporate other ongoing feature branches into their own is not teamwork, it is mutual fighting. Communicate with your teammates. Cooperate! That's what a team is.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185929/how-can-i-rebase-in-git-without-resolving-other-commit-conflicts-or-squash-all - this person has gotten into a mess. Better not to go there...

Comment: @matt about your first question, I don't understand, of course git-pull merges two branches. So if you pull from B to my branch (A) it would merge B in A. About the rest of your answers I tend to agree, it seems to me as a terrible ideea too, that's why I want to check here first.

Comment: Not necessarily. "pull" has no fixed meaning of its own. It is a fetch followed by a merge or rebase, depending on your config, so it's important to establish what your pull would do.

Comment: @matt I understand the "pull" command cand be used in different ways, but come on, when you say you pull FROM some branch TO another isn't it pretty obvious what it's meant?

Comment: I was tempted to vote to close this as opinion based - matts' comments and eftshift0s' answer made me do it. Not because I think they're wrong - just because it solidified my belief that it truly is opinion based. Some would argue that it's the best thing in the world - while real life shows the horrors you can get into.

Comment: @fredrik I disagree.  Yes, it is possible for people to express opinions on this topic; but the questions asked are factual in nature.  OP didn't ask "is this a good thing to do"; OP asked "is this a good thing to do IN GITFLOW".  You can have an opinion about whether GitFlow is a good branch/merge process, but what procedures GitFlow does or doesn't allow is a factual matter, as are its documented reasons for those decisions.  In fact, if you look at OP's *specific* questions:  "Is there a disadvantage to...?"  Factual.  "Is there a way to ___ automatically?"  Factual.

Comment: The last question ("is there a better way...") is somewhat opinion based (though still this should be taken in context of the question being about GitFlow), but is also VERY typical for SO and, in context of the broader question, would not be a reaosn to close

Comment: @fredrik no one here argued it's "the best thing in the world" seems pretty obvious there's a consensus that it something to be avoided. And I don't know why you would judge the question by the fact that some people gave an opinion that it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is *doable* but requires finesse to achieve it without messing up. So... my first advice: keep *your changes* straight (no merges) and together, so that they are easily moved later on when needed. So,  first, we move branch A *on top* of branch B (that is so that you can keep on working on top of branchA, your branch):

```
git rebase --onto=branchB your-base-branch branchA # base branch is origin/main or whatever
```

So, now you can continue working on top of branchA... Now, suppose that the developer of branchB *rebased* his branch.... this is one of the times when you need to be careful:

```
git rebase --onto=branchB old-branchB-position branchA
```

This is so that your changes can be set on top of the new position of branchB. But I see the question coming: Why not just run `git rebase branchB`? BranchB is *not* your responsibility.... the developer might have broken it in pieces beyond recognition and might not have any resemblance to the *original branchB* that you first got yourself on top of... so you need to be extra careful to *not* move those original revisions when you rebase your branch.

Comment: It's interesting though I'd rather not try it in real life. I'll probably just wait for B to be merged to develop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this in git - such as what eftshift0 suggests in their answer.  But you asked specifically about gitflow.  So let's take that into account.  Note that there is no law saying you have to follow gitflow, or that your team can't choose to invent some variation on gitflow that better suits your own needs; but that should be a deliberate team discussion where you pay attention to not only what you gain from your changes, but also what they cost you.

> Is there any disadvantage to pulling from branch B (or is it even at all recommanded to pull from other branches than develop)?

Yes.  Once you have pulled branch B into branch A, if you merge branch B into dev you wlil be carrying an incomplete set of branch B's changes, which may result in a broken state on dev.  This compromises the idea that you should be able to make a release branch from dev at any time.

Rebasing branch A onto branch B has the same disadvantage.

You can mitigate that if you can make sure to merge branch B back to dev before you merge branch A back to dev; that may or may not defeat the purpose of integrating branch B into branch A early.  And that's not to say there's no way to handle it; but pulling (or otherwise merging) one story branch into another does generally carry risk.

> I realize I would now have to sync with both develop, and branch B, so next time I want the latest changes I'll need to pull from both. Is there a way to do this automatically? What if my branch depends on more than 2 branches?

There are some assumptions built into that, but if we stick with your premises:  No, there is not an easy way to set the branch up to track multiple other branches.  You could try to script something but such a script would probably be error-prone.  The underlying problem is that if conflicts are possible, then you have to merge one branch at a time and resolve each merge before starting the next (which is a manual process).  And if branch A is entangled enough with branch B for this conversation to be happening, then conflicts are possible.

Now, the idea that you would want to track branch B... why?  The case where you depend on code that branch B has already written is already an edge case; if you depend on branch B's ongoing work, then you should consider if it is too soon to be working the story on branch A.  (At a minimum gitflow isn't set up to work such entwined stories concurrently; even in a continuous integration model I would have questions about whether it's a good idea.)

More generally, it sounds like you're thinking of your feature branches as long-lived entities where you need to plan for maintenance.  Ideally that should be avoided or, at most, an exception case.

> Is there a better way to do this other than wait for branch B to be merged to develop?

As far as I've been able to tell, the gitflow branching strategy doesn't really address the situation you're talking about.  Perhaps it assumes feature branches will be granular enough that this won't come up (or at least that it won't be too much bother to block one story until the other is done), or that your processes should provide you a way to avoid it.  I guess it's even possible that they just didn't consider the possibility when developing/documenting the model.  But one way or other, no documentation I've seen gives a good answer.

If you can't wait for branch B, then the next best solution is to copy selectively from branch B those changes that you would've made in branch A if branch B weren't a thing.  This probably calls for `git cherry-pick`.  (I often refer to cherry-pick as the most over-recommended command in git, but this is one of the use cases for which it's actually a good fit.)

That works best if the changes you want are in separate commits from any other changes.  In that case, you can simply cherry-pick those commits to your branch.  If the changes are mixed in with other commits, then you should consider being more selective - such as using `cherry-pick -n` and then only staging and committing the changes you need.

Be aware that this may cause merge conflicts as you integrate the two branches back to dev.  The good news is that generally both "sides" of the merge will be the same, so they might auto-resolve.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Of course it's "opinion based", nothing really stops you from doing this, you can always shoot yourself in the foot, but it's pretty obvious from these answers that I wasn't missing anything, gitflow just isn't built to make this easy.